-AN Fitting Compatibility
I have a -6 AN fitting on the end of a hose. I am not familiar with AN fittings and I don't understand how to interpret the table at the bottom of the Wikipedia page on this subject. Does this table indicate that I could connect 3/8-18 NPT to the -6 AN fitting?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN_thread

Never worked with one unless it was on a car part, but this search result  https://www.mfcp.com/our-blog/an-jic-37-flare-fittings points out the different thread type. Illustrated in the pic are AN standard having class 3A UNJ/UNJF thread form with radiused root. Contemporary SAE replacement seems to return to UN/UNF thread form. Sorry this isn't a complete answer ... I'd check a reference like Machinery's handbook but the last 2 I had walked away
